# Does Batching REST API calls save on API Limits?

Tags: rest-api

If I access SObject records via batching as defined [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_batch.htm), does that count as 1 call for the purposes of daily API limits, or does each subrequest within the batch count as 1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [linked](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_batch.htm) Batch documentation:

> Each subrequest counts against rate limits.

So, if you perform 25 subrequests, they will each contribute to the overall limit independently.

Another relevant part of the same document:

> Subrequests execute serially in their order in the request body. When a subrequest executes successfully, it commits its data. Commits are reflected in the output of later subrequests. If a subrequest fails, commits made by previous subrequests are not rolled back.

Notice how each sub request is being processed and committed in isolation. Hence they count towards the limits separately.

Comment: Ugh, totally missed that. Thanks. I'll accept as soon as the timer lets me.

Comment: No problem. I think the main intention of the REST API batching is to reduce the the round-trip delay.